# books on the application of linear algebra on statistics/finance/machine learning

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-programming, finance, machine-learning

I am reading "linear algebra done right" by Axler and like it a lot. One thing though, in the end I would like to put these theory to use and as a math textbook it doesn't cover much application. 
Would you recommend any good book that **covers application but also tries to tie back to the theory**. It would be even better, if the subject is mostly focused on statistics/finance/machine learning.

Or some other book that has a balance between matrix and linear algebra theory, as Axler doesn't cover much matrix until the end. (how about Linear Algebra by FriedbergInsel/Spence?)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I am reading Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher M. Bishop.  I think it may qualify for your criteria.